# PowerShell update WPF window on event

Tags: wpf, powershell

I am building a WPF UI with PowerShell, so that users can (among other thing), dictate whether or not a NIC should be configured to use DHCP or be statically configured. I want either a combobox with "DHCP" and "Static" or two buttons.

If the user selects "Static", then I want to update the window to show "IP", "Subnet", and "Gateway" textboxes.

I can't seem to find any way to add a new text box and label to an existing window. Here is the XAML I have (showing where the IP config fields should be). Where do I go from here?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="IPMI Config Tool" Height="321.563" Width="421.361">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="415">
        <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Margin="10,10,145.907,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Specify the IP config information for the IPMI port. If you click the Cancel button, you may not be prompted again."/></TextBlock>
        <Label x:Name="ipTypeLabel" Content="IP Config Type*" Margin="21,71,243,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,100,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="DHCP" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Static" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="118"/>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label x:Name="ipLabel" Content="Static IPMI IP*" Margin="21,161,243,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="ipTxt" Height="26" Margin="177,161,82,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Static IP for the IPMI port."/>
        <Label x:Name="maskLabel" Content="Static IPMI Subnet Mask*" Margin="21,188,111,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="maskTxt" Height="26" Margin="177,188,82,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Static subnet mask for the IPMI port."/>
        <Label x:Name="gatewayLabel" Content="Static IPMI Gateway IP*" Margin="21,215,243,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="gatewayTxt" Height="26" Margin="177,215,82,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" ToolTip="Static gateway IP for the IPMI port."/>
        <Button x:Name="okButton" Content="OK" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18.928,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" IsDefault="True"/>
        <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Content="Cancel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="80.317,0,0,10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="50" IsCancel="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: How the `PowerShell script` is supposed to run? In a separate window?

Comment: The idea is that the script is run, which loads the (separate) WPF window. I supposed I could do a WPF with two buttons, and if you select "static", then a second window opens, but that doesn't seem as elegant.

Comment: What exaclty is your question? Do you know how an event handler work?

Comment: I can't find a method that will display a text box (and label) when a button is clicked. Is that possible?